# Error: could not find `rng` in `rand` when using Rust Crate `secp256k1`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates, secp256k1

I am new to rust and encountered the following error when trying to use the `secp256k1` crate with the [provided example code](https://docs.rs/secp256k1/0.20.1/secp256k1/#secp256k1)

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `secp256k1::rand::rng`
 --> src/main.rs:1:22
  |
1 | use secp256k1::rand::rng::OsRng;
  |                      ^^^ could not find `rng` in `rand`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

My code is really simple

```
use secp256k1::rand::rng::OsRng;
use secp256k1::Secp256k1;

fn main() {
    let secp = Secp256k1::new();
    let mut rng = OsRng::new().expect("OsRng");
}
```

with the `Cargo.toml` containing

```
[dependencies]
secp256k1 = {version="0.20.1", features = ["rand"]}
```

Are we missing something to get this working?

I tried using `rustc 1.22.1 (b01adbbc3 2020-07-08)` and then `rustc 1.51.0 (2fd73fabe 2021-03-23)`

Comment: Try changing `secp256k1::rand::rng::OsRng` to `secp256k1::rand::rngs::OsRng`. It looks like the module was renamed and the authors of `secp256k1` have not updated their documentation yet.

Comment: @Locke Renamed to `secp256k1::rand::rngs::OsRng` and still getting a new error: *no `OsRng` in `rand::rngs`*

Comment: Then you need to also add the `std` feature to `rand`. You can do this by adding it as a dependency `rand = {version = "0.6", features = ["std"]}`. `0.6` is the version used by `secp256k1`. You might also be able to add it to the default features as `[features] default = ["rand/std"]`, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: @Locke Adding `rand = {version = "0.6", features = ["std"]}` got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Fwiw, it seems you can now just enable the "rand-std" feature on secp256k1 now instead of doing all that.